# Cluster has already maximum shards open

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Windows 10 and I'm getting

> Elasticsearch exception [type=validation_exception, reason=Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;]

How can I resolve this? I don't mind if I lose data since it only runs locally.

Comment: Delete some of your oldest indices or add one more node

Answer (score 26):

Aside from the answers mentioned above, you can also try increasing the shards until you try to rearchitect the nodes

```sh
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "persistent": { "cluster.max_shards_per_node": "3000" } }'
```

Besides, the following can be useful the should be proceeded with `CAUTION` ofcourse

- Get total number of unassigned shards in cluster

```sh
curl -XGET -u elasticuser:yourpassword http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty | grep unassigned_shards
```

#### USE WITH CAUTION

- To DELETE the unassigned shards in a cluster `(USE WITH CAUTION)`

```sh
curl -XGET -u elasticuser:yourpassword http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED | awk {'print $1'} #(USE WITH CAUTION) | xargs -i curl  -XDELETE -u elasticuser:yourpassword "http://localhost:9200/{}"
```

Comment: Do not run the delete unassigned shards command : it deletes the indices, not the shards.

Answer (score 13):

You are reaching the limit ***cluster.max_shards_per_node***. Add more data node or reduce the number of shards in cluster.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Try setting it dynamically on a running Elasticsearch cluster with following curl command : curl -XPUT $CLUSTER_URL/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data-binary $'{"transient":{"cluster.max_shards_per_node":5100}}'

Comment: @Amitkumar : Reduce the number of shards? Shouldn't it be Increased ?

Comment: @Sandun Amit probably meant deleting some of the existing indexes that maybe are not needed anymore

Answer (score 13):

If you don't mind about the data loss, delete old indicies.
The easy way is do it from the GUI *Kibana > Management > DevTools*, then to get all indicies:

```
GET /_cat/indices/
```

You can delete within a pattern like below:

```
DELETE /<index-name>
```

e.g.:

```
DELETE /logstash-2020-10*
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have too many shards per node.

May I suggest you look at the following resources about sizing:

https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/quantitative-cluster-sizing

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, "maximum shards open", so *closing* indices also work, no need to delete them if you want to keep them for later. Closed indices cannot be queried but data remains.